# Expandable forms with UITableView?

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard

I haave to implement 3 seperate forms, but they have headers which make the forms collapsible when clicked.

When searching online I saw the expanding rows for UITableView. Is it possible to add a custom form view in the expanded view of the tableView? Or do I try another approach with 3 hidden views that appear when each of the header sections are selected?

Comment: Have a look at [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka). Or use SwiftUI.

Answer (score 0):

I always use UIStackView inside my cell. And when user click expand button, i unhide views and call tablewview.reloadData(). This is my approach

Comment: Thank you for the reply! You are suggesting I use a combination of both methods right? I will try this out. 

One Doubt, How do I place a UIStackView under its corresponding header? I have to implement 3 different forms in an expanding header table

Answer (score 0):

You can use 3 stack views. Each stack view will have a heading label and a tableview inside it. By default all the tableviews are hidden and heading label are not hidden. Add a tap gesture to heading labels. Whenever user taps a heading label you can unhide the respective tableview. You can give tags to each heading label and tableview so you can identify which heading label is tapped, like if a user tapped heading label with tag 1, you will unhide the tableview with tag 1.